# Convert from utf-8 byte array to string and back yields different data

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to figure out a very basic issue:
I have a byte array with 8 bytes, containing data.
I would like to convert it to string and then, on the "other side", to encode it back to the exact byte array.
For some reason - this is not working.
The value I'm using is 22.22 (double) and it represented as 8 bytes with the values:
184, 30,133,235,81,56,54,64
I would expect the byteArrayList **single** item (for complicity) which, in my case contains 8 bytes  to be identical to the result item - they are not identical - the result contsins 14 bytes !!!!
This is the result:
239, 191, 189, 30, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 81, 56, 54, 64

It appears as if both the byteArrayList single item and the result contians some escape characters (\u001b in hexadecimal)
What am I missing here ?
Here is my code:

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = new List<byte[]>();
...Here I populate the byteArrayList with 1 item - 8 bytes long
UTFEncoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
foreach(byte[] byteArrayItem in byteArrayList)//currently - for simplicity contains one item
{
    SB.Append(encoding.GetString(byteArrayItem ));
}
string items = SB.ToString();
byte[] result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(items); //I would expect the result to be identical to the byteArrayList  - it is not ! it contains 12 bytes !!!!
```

Comment: For the record: you don't start with a "utf-8 byte array", you start with a byte array with *some arbitrary data that's not (necessarily) a UTF-8 encoded string*. That's a very important distinction.

Answer (score 3):

Not every sequence of bytes is valid UTF-8, so you can't use UTF-8 this way. You need to use an encoding that  can handle an arbitrary sequence of bytes, such as Base64 or Hex.

The sequence 239, 181, 189 is the UTF-8 encoding of [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). This is the character used to indicate a decoding error.

Comment: I replaced the utf-8 encoder with an ascii - but still - a question mark (?) is being inserted when executing the encoding.GetString method

Comment: ASCII also cannot encode all byte sequences (184 is not a valid byte in ASCII, for example). You will need an encoding that can encode arbitrary sequences of bytes, such as Base64 or Hex. Alternately you could string-encode your double as "22.22" (0x32322e3232).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string